# Can't get slide out menu to display properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a link to the site in progress -- http://barret.co/resources/testsite12345/

There is almost nothing on the site yet as I am working on the skeleton, so inspecting element should be very easy to pinpoint what's wrong.

I'm working on a slide out menu from scratch but am fairly new to jQuery. Basically, what I have now is working, but not exactly how I'd like it to be. as you can see, when you click the menu button in top left, it slides the panel left and back to the right. I'd like for this panel to initially be hidden upon viewing the page, and then slide out when menu is clicked.

Also, is there an easy way to close this panel if a user clicks onto the main page? The only way it closes now is if the menu button is clicked again.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply had a mixup with the classes.

Add this to your `#left-menu` css:

```
right: 300px;
```

and then use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#menu-container #right-menu').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('#left-menu');
    if (! hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"right":"300px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    }
    });
}); // end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Maybe it has to do with my css?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Forgot to add the initial position.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following: $(".logo").hide() to the $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: Or $("#menu-container").hide()

Comment: I'm not sure I posed the question correctly. I'm not trying to hide the logo. I just didn't include the image for the logo which is why it's hidden. I am trying to hide #left-menu.

Comment: However, I did try the code you sent with #left-menu instead of logo and it hid it but it will not return when clicked

Comment: try #left-menu and put $("#left-menu").show() inside the slide in function on top of everything

Comment: if you still have problems please post your script so I can help you

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#menu-container #right-menu').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('#left-menu');
    if (! hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"right":"300px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    }
    });
}); // end

Comment: And the css: #menu-container{
width:300px;
float:left;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
-webkit-transition:.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:.8s ease-in-out;
}

#left-menu{
width:300px;
background-color:#454545;
position:absolute;
top:93px;
}

#right-menu{
float:left;
}